# PHP: Count a stdClass object

Tags: php, count, stdclass

I have a stdClass object created from json_decode that won't return the right number when I run the count($obj) function.  The object has 30 properties, but the return on the count() function is say 1.

Any ideas?

Below is an example of one of the objects.  (I'm requesting the daily trend information from Twitter).  If this object had more than one property, the count($obj) would equal 1.

```
[trends] => stdClass Object
    (
        [2009-08-21 11:05] => Array
            (
                [0] => stdClass Object
                    (
                        [query] => "Follow Friday"
                        [name] => Follow Friday
                    )

                [1] => stdClass Object
                    (
                        [query] => "Inglourious Basterds" OR "Inglorious Basterds"
                        [name] => Inglourious Basterds
                    )

                [2] => stdClass Object
                    (
                        [query] => Inglourious
                        [name] => Inglourious
                    )

                [3] => stdClass Object
                    (
                        [query] => #songsincode
                        [name] => #songsincode
                    )

                [4] => stdClass Object
                    (
                        [query] => #shoutout
                        [name] => #shoutout
                    )

                [5] => stdClass Object
                    (
                        [query] => "District 9"
                        [name] => District 9
                    )

                [6] => stdClass Object
                    (
                        [query] => #howmanypeople
                        [name] => #howmanypeople
                    )

                [7] => stdClass Object
                    (
                        [query] => Ashes OR #ashes
                        [name] => Ashes
                    )

                [8] => stdClass Object
                    (
                        [query] => #youtubefail
                        [name] => #youtubefail
                    )

                [9] => stdClass Object
                    (
                        [query] => TGIF
                        [name] => TGIF
                    )

                [10] => stdClass Object
                    (
                        [query] => #wish09
                        [name] => #wish09
                    )

                [11] => stdClass Object
                    (
                        [query] => #watch
                        [name] => #watch
                    )

                [12] => stdClass Object
                    (
                        [query] => Avatar
                        [name] => Avatar
                    )

                [13] => stdClass Object
                    (
                        [query] => Ramadhan
                        [name] => Ramadhan
                    )

                [14] => stdClass Object
                    (
                        [query] => Goodnight
                        [name] => Goodnight
                    )

                [15] => stdClass Object
                    (
                        [query] => iPhone
                        [name] => iPhone
                    )

                [16] => stdClass Object
                    (
                        [query] => #iranelection
                        [name] => #iranelection
                    )

                [17] => stdClass Object
                    (
                        [query] => Apple
                        [name] => Apple
                    )

                [18] => stdClass Object
                    (
                        [query] => "Usain Bolt"
                        [name] => Usain Bolt
                    )

                [19] => stdClass Object
                    (
                        [query] => H1N1
                        [name] => H1N1
                    )

            )
     )
```

Comment: Could you clarify your example? As you posted it, it is has one property `2009-08-21 11:05`, being an array with 20 entries, so count($trends) would rightfully return 1.

Comment: As [Steven pointed out](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1314745/php-count-an-stdclass-object/1314754#1314754), the Object is of type stdClass, which does not implement the Countable interface, thus count(<stdClass object>) will always return 1.

Comment: Hopel, you're exactly right.  If I cast the object to an array it returns the correct number!  Excellent.

Comment: you might want to accept an answer. especially geiven that you wrote in the comment that the first given answer works for you.

Answer (score 327, accepted):

The problem is that count is intended to count the indexes in an array, not the properties on an object, (unless it's a custom object that implements the Countable interface). Try casting the object, like below, as an array and seeing if that helps.

```
$total = count((array)$obj);
```

Simply casting an object as an array won't always work but being a simple stdClass object it should get the job done here.

Comment: be ware that private properties will appear in the resultant array, wich is really unexpected.

Comment: While this method works, I would not use it for implementation because future versions of PHP could cause this code to break, I much prefer Alan Strom's answer.

Answer (score 133):

The count function is meant to be used on

1. Arrays
2. Objects that are derived from classes that implement the countable interface

A stdClass is neither of these.  The easier/quickest way to accomplish what you're after is

```
$count = count(get_object_vars($some_std_class_object));
```

This uses PHP's [get_object_vars](http://php.net/get_object_vars) function, which will return the properties of an object as an array.  You can then use this array with PHP's count function.

Comment: Before PHP 7, `get_object_vars()` on an `stdClass` that resulted from casting an array to an object will yield an empty array. Casting the `stdClass` instance to array, on the other hand, works everywhere.

Comment: Works for me on PHP 5.6.30

Answer (score 9):

The object doesn't have 30 properties. It has one, which is an array that has 30 elements. You need the number of elements in that array.

Comment: Poking at the data a little more, it might be better to use the $assoc param with json_encode, which converts it to an array. That property you're getting is named from the timestamp which is going to be a right pain to access regularly. As an array you could just do count( $trends[0] );

Comment: I probably should have given a better example.  The stdClass object has more than just the one I gave in the example.  It has 32, each containing an array with 20 elements.

Answer (score 5):

There is nothing wrong with count() here, "trends" is the only key that is being counted in this case, you can try doing:

```
count($obj->trends);
```

Or:

```
count($obj->trends['2009-08-21 11:05']);
```

Or maybe even doing:

```
count($obj, COUNT_RECURSIVE);
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use this

```
$i=0;
foreach ($object as $key =>$value)
{
$i++;
}
```

the variable `$i` is number of keys.

Answer (score 1):

You can use ArrayIterator for that purpose.

```php
(new \ArrayIterator($obj))->count()
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use `sizeof()` function to get the length of any object in PHP!

Comment: It's just an alias of `count()`: https://www.php.net/sizeof

Answer (score -1):

Count Normal  arrya or object

```
count($object_or_array);
```

Count multidimensional arrya or object

```
count($object_or_array, 1); // 1 for  multidimensional array count, 0 for Default
```

Answer (score -5):

`count()` function works with array. But if you want to count object's length then you can use this method.

```
$total = $obj->length;
```