# PHP: Count number of objects within another object?

Tags: php, object, stdclass

I'm still new at PHP and I can't seem to count the number of Objects within another object. The stdClass object looks like this:

```
stdClass Object (

[data] => Array (
    [0] => stdClass Object (
        [Code] => ABC
        [Title] => Alphabet
        [sections] => Array (
            [0] => stdClass Object (
                [Name] => Sounds
                [sections] => Vowels
            )
        )
    )

)
```

I must count the number of elements in this object so i can echo it properly. For the data, I was able to do it:

```
$number = count($hanap->data);
```

I don't know how to do it for the sections.

```
$number = count($hanap->data->sections); // does not work.
```

Thanks. Any help will be greatly appreciated. :)

Comment: $total = count((array)$obj); http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1314745/php-count-an-stdclass-object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
count($hanap->data[0]->sections)
```

Answer (score 2):

this will solve your problem, just cast the object to array and count it

```
$total = count((array)$obj);
```

[PHP: Count an stdClass object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1314745/php-count-an-stdclass-object)

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the first member of the array where they are...

```
$number = count($hanap->data[0]->sections)
```