# check if a record is in db - php

Tags: php, database, codeigniter, record

Well i have a problem. I should check if an email is in my database.
I'm using CI (CodeIgniter)

MODEL:

```
   function getUsersPoints($email)
{
$query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM `points` WHERE `p_email` = '$email'");
return $query->result();
}
```

CONTROLLER:
it comes a function that inserts all the data in table `customers`, and then i should check if the email is in the second table `points`, and if not, i should add it. so, what i have done:

```
$this->model->insert_customer($firstname, $lastname, $email, $telephone, $street, $house);
$getUserPoints = $this->model->getUsersPoints($email);

if(count($getUserPoints) == 0)
    echo "ADD in table points";
else
    echo "DO SOMETHING ELSE";
```

Can someone tell me what i'm doing wrong?

Comment: I think that problem, maybe, lies here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1314745/php-count-an-stdclass-object Try to return result_array()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ActiveRecord's result() returns object, but you want to count() it, so you need to use ->result_array():

```
function getUsersPoints($email) {
    $query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM `points` WHERE `p_email` = '$email'");
    return $query->result_array();
}
```

You can also use ->count_all_results() in model, it will return just count. But I think, in such case you should use another ActiveRecords methods enstead of query.

Answer (score 0):

```
function getUserPoints($email){
return $this->db->where('email', $email)->count_all_results('points');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$data = array(  `p_email` => $email);
$query = $this->db->get_where('points',$data);
if($query->num_rows() == 0)
{
   //Write your code
}
else
{
   //your code
}
```