# count of stdClass objects Array in php

Tags: php, arrays, count

I have following array of `stdClass Object` structure and want count number of offers. Std class is received as a response from third party API so it is dynamic.

```
stdClass Object
    (
        [Offer] => Array
            (
                [0] => stdClass Object
                    (
                        [Offerid] => 1
                        [LoanAmount] => 2****
                        [InterestRate] => 2*
                        [Term] => 36
                        [MonthlyPayment] => 7***
                        [Annualfee] => 0
                        [OriginationFee] => 1***

                    )

                [1] => stdClass Object
                    (
                        [Offerid] => 1
                        [LoanAmount] => 2****
                        [InterestRate] => 2*
                        [Term] => 36
                        [MonthlyPayment] => 7***
                        [Annualfee] => 0
                        [OriginationFee] => 1***
                    )

                [2] => stdClass Object
                    (
                        [Offerid] => 1
                        [LoanAmount] => 2****
                        [InterestRate] => 2*
                        [Term] => 36
                        [MonthlyPayment] => 7***
                        [Annualfee] => 0
                        [OriginationFee] => 1***
                    )

            )

    )
```

i want count number of arrays in **[Offer]**, for that i have done following:

```
echo "count----------".count($offers);
```

but it gives **1** as a count like
`count----------1`
in this case count is **3** and i want 3 as output.
Please suggests.
i have also used this
       echo "count----------".count((array)$offers);
This also dont works.

Comment: Try  - `count($your_object->Offer)`.

Comment: i have already tried this, it also gives 1.

Comment: Can you make a fiddle on https://eval.in/??

Comment: Can you show more of your work. How is $offers defined.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP: Count an stdClass object](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1314745/php-count-an-stdclass-object)

Comment: it should work count($your_object->Offer) or try to cast object into array. $totalCount = count((array)$stdObject);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved my question by following way:

```
foreach ($offers as $key=> $value) 
{
   echo "<br/>count->".count($value);
}
```

this loops itreate only once, and give me result.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like convert "stdClass Object" into normal array and try after that count($offer);

Just write (array)$object; It will convert as normal array

Comment: That's a comment and not an answer.

Comment: please provide code also. If its a suggestion, please use comments.

Answer (score 0):

Count should work.

```
<?php
$obj = new stdClass();
$obj->Offer = array(
    array('Offerid' => 1, 'LoanAmount' => '2***', 'InterestRate' => '2*', 'Term' => 36, 'MonthlyPayment' => '7***', 'Annualfee' => 0, 'OriginationFee' => '1***'),
    array('Offerid' => 1, 'LoanAmount' => '2***', 'InterestRate' => '2*', 'Term' => 36, 'MonthlyPayment' => '7***', 'Annualfee' => 0, 'OriginationFee' => '1***'),
    array('Offerid' => 1, 'LoanAmount' => '2***', 'InterestRate' => '2*', 'Term' => 36, 'MonthlyPayment' => '7***', 'Annualfee' => 0, 'OriginationFee' => '1***'),
);
echo count($obj->Offer); // Outputs 3
?>
```

[Live example](https://eval.in/463470)

Comment: thanks for answer,but i cant do like this.because above response is dyanmic and it was send by APi.

Comment: What you can't do? `var_dump(isset($object->Offer)); //true` and `var_dump(isset($object->Offera)); // false`

Answer (score 0):

**Try this :**

```
<?php
class Example {
    public $public = 'prop:public';
    private $prv   = 'prop:private';
    protected $prt = 'prop:protected';
}

$arrayobj = new ArrayObject(new Example());
var_dump($arrayobj->count());

$arrayobj = new ArrayObject(array('first','second','third'));
var_dump($arrayobj->count());
?>
```

The above example will output:

```
int(1)
int(3)
```

[Answer Source](http://php.net/manual/en/arrayobject.count.php)