# How to count this object array?

Tags: php, object

So i've been trying to count this object array for ages, and nothing seem to work for me...

```
stdClass Object
(
    [type] => champion
    [version] => 5.24.2
    [data] => stdClass Object
        (
            [Thresh] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [id] => 412
                    [key] => Thresh
                    [name] => Thresh
                    [title] => the Chain Warden
                    [info] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [attack] => 5
                            [defense] => 6
                            [magic] => 6
                            [difficulty] => 7
                        )

                )

            [Aatrox] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [id] => 266
                    [key] => Aatrox
                    [name] => Aatrox
                    [title] => the Darkin Blade
                    [info] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [attack] => 8
                            [defense] => 4
                            [magic] => 3
                            [difficulty] => 4
                        )

                )

            [Tryndamere] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [id] => 23
                    [key] => Tryndamere
                    [name] => Tryndamere
                    [title] => the Barbarian King
                    [info] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [attack] => 10
                            [defense] => 5
                            [magic] => 2
                            [difficulty] => 5
                        )

                )

            [Ezreal] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [id] => 81
                    [key] => Ezreal
                    [name] => Ezreal
                    [title] => the Prodigal Explorer
                    [info] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [attack] => 7
                            [defense] => 2
                            [magic] => 6
                            [difficulty] => 7
                        )

                )

        )

)
```

What i want to count is the length of `data`.

**Plot Twist:** `count($array->data)` doesn't work.

If it counts right, it should return 3. Thank you in advance!

Comment: This is the same as: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1314745/php-count-an-stdclass-object

Comment: Wait what? Are these League of Legends Champions? :D

Comment: Haha awesome :D Which server do you play on? I play on EUW :D fizz main :D

Comment: Lol. I think we should keep league out of Stack Overflow xD But i play on EUW. Name: whattowritehere

Comment: add me on gmail ali.zia.1991@gmail.com and summoner's name "Syed Ali Zia" => Silver 5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your case `data` is an object. Cast it to array:

```
 $count = count((array) $array->data);
```

the other way is using `get_object_vars`

```
$count = count(get_object_vars($array->data));
```

Comment: Thank you! works perfect. Couldn't seem to find this no matter how much i googled...

Answer (score 1):

Not that hard, you can do this:

`$object = [ .... ]; // The object you show above.`

```
function countElements($object) {
    return count(get_object_vars($object));
}

$count = countElements($object);
```

That should get you the answer.

[get_object_vars()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-object-vars.php) documentation.

Answer (score 1):

Used below code:

```
count((array)$array->data);
```

Instead of:

```
count($array->data);
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply use `count((array) $array->data);`