# laravel : count(): Parameter must be an array or an object that implements Countable

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.3

I'm using Laravel 5.3 and my php ver is 7.1

when i called SoftDeletes class i get that error

ErrorException in Builder.php line 1231:
count(): Parameter must be an array or an object that implements Countable

this is my model

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletes;


class Post extends Model
{

    use SoftDeletes;

    protected $dates = ['deleted_at'];

    protected $fillable = [

        'title','content','image','category_id','slug'
    ];



    public function category(){


        return $this->belongsTo('App\Category');
    }
}
```

and it is my controller

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use App\Post;

use App\Category;

use Session;

class PostsController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index()
    {



        return view('admin.posts.index')->with('posts',Post::all());

    }

    /**
     * Show the form for creating a new resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function create()
    {
        $category = Category::all();

        if($category->count() == 0){

            Session::flash('info' , 'You must create at least 1 category to add a new post');

            return redirect()->back();
        }

        return view('admin.posts.post')->with('categories',$category);
    }

    /**
     * Store a newly created resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function store(Request $request)
    {

        $this->validate($request,[

            'title'         => 'required|max:255',
            'image'         => 'required|image',
            'content'       => 'required',
            'category_id'   => 'required'
        ]);


        $image = $request->image;

        $image_new_name = time().$image->getClientOriginalName();

        $image->move('/uploads/posts' , $image_new_name);



        $post= Post::create([

            'title'          => $request->title,
            'image'          => '/uploads/posts/' . $image_new_name,
            'content'        => $request->content,
            'category_id'    => $request->category_id,
            'slug'           => str_slug($request->title)
        ]);

        Session::flash('success' , 'You created a new post');

        return redirect()->back();



    }

    /**
     * Display the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function show($id)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for editing the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function edit($id)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Update the specified resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function update(Request $request, $id)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Remove the specified resource from storage.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function destroy($id)
    {
        //
    }
}
```

and when i delete the count() function also get the same error

how can i solve this error

Comment: You'll need to look deeper, the problem is not with the code you posted. The error message should indicate a file name and line number, where `count()` is called. To help you debug this, we need to know what is being passed to `count()` and where it came from.

Answer (score 5):

Laravel 5.3 and my PHP ver is 7.1 is not compatible with each other
[Refer to this issue in the github](https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/20248)

To solve this error you can do two things

- Upgrade laravel 5.3 to laravel 5.5 refer this ( [5.3 to 5.4](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/upgrade), [5.4 to 5.5](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/upgrade) )
- Downgrade you php to php 5.6

Answer (score 0):

I changed line 1231 in `C:\laragon\www\mystore\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Eloquent`

to

```
$originalWhereCount = !empty($query->wheres) ? count($query->wheres) : 0;
```

Comment: Changing the code in the vendor directory is never a good idea.

- These changes will vanish once you run composer update or install command
- These kinds of changes can bring you very unexpected behaviour in the application
- Trust me this is not an optimal solution as it will break the code in another area
```
I personally suggest to check your laravel and php dependency and upgrade PHP/laravel which is supported.
In this case. Php 5.6 is supported not PHP 7.2.
```

Comment: In our situation, with an old project, it was our only solution until we could upgrade the php and laravel version.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with the laravel `find()` method returning an object and not an array.  Therefore the `count()` method will not work.  Try:
[Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1314745/php-count-a-stdclass-object) solution or

```
Post::all()->toArray();
```

Will return an array that will work with the `count()` method.

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround add this to your routes file:

```
if(version_compare(PHP_VERSION, '7.2.0', '>=')) {
    error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE ^ E_WARNING);
}
```